# Keep track of file access using IIS and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to put an unique image (1x1) on an e-mail marketing (not spam) of my client. Just like www.spypig.com, I'd like to use it to know how many people have actually read the e-mail. I guess I'll have to check how many times this unique image has been accessed, but I can't figure out how to do it.

So my question is: Is there a way to check how many times an image file was accessed using ASP.NET/C#?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tracking Email Reads using ASP.NET** 
http://www.aspnetemail.com/samples/emailtracker/default.aspx

Shows how to use a beacon image to track email reads (and some other techniques).

Note that image techniques will only work if the recipient’s mail client allows images to be displayed, and allow http requests to remote web servers for downloading images. It is entirely possible to read email in its text only form, and thus never know when an email has been read.